# MonoTouch AVFoundation Puzzle

Tags: xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I'm new with MonoTouch.
I want to pick frames from video (I found this page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html), but it's written in Object-C, I've never learned that. Can Someone give me a MonoTouch sample. Appreciated.

Comment: The only way this will be possible is if MonoTouch has wrapped the AVFoundation API. Check the MonoTouch documentation. Looking at mono touch it seems possible to link to arbitrary libraries. Take a look at [link](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries)

Comment: My teacher tells me someone implement it, but he doesn't bring his code out.That's just I want.But thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Today I wrote a sample, but the APIs in MonoTouch 4.0 were not very good, they were fairly hard to use.   We made some changes to MonoTouch today, and the next alpha release in the next few days will have these changes in.

The sample code has been ported and lives now in http://github.com/migueldeicaza/monotouch-samples/av-capture-frames module most of the code is in Main.cs